# Retrieving multiple strings from one line of a log

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a huge `ACS.txt` report created in `Kiwi`, and I'd like to:

ID particular lines which have a set string `"RADIUS Accounting"` then ....

...from those lines take two values `"User-ID=XXXXXXXX@domain.com"` and `"MAC=xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx"`, then output that in a txt.

This is what I have right now

```
Get-Content C:ACS.txt | ForEach-Object { 
    $null = $_ -match "RADIUS Accounting",\s.*User-Name=(?<user>[0-9]+@domain.com).*Calling-Station-ID=(?<mac>([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})).*"; $matches.user; $matches.mac
}
```

I think it's giving me what I want, it's just in one long list, rather than user/mac per line.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include a complete sample line.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Select-String and iterate the found (sub)matches
building a new PSCustomObject you can export or view

```
$UserMac = Select-String -Path C:ACS.txt -Pattern "RADIUS Accounting.*User-Name=([0-9]+@domain.com).*Calling-Station-ID=(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))" |
    ForEach-Object{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            User = $matches.Groups[1].Value
            Mac  = $matches.Groups[2].Value
    }
}
# $UserMac
$UserMac | Out-Gridview
# $UserMac | Export-Csv .\UserMac.csv -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks, however this returns the exception: 'Cannot index into a null array.
At line:4 char:36
+             User = $matches.Groups[ <<<< 1].Value
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray'

Comment: What PowerShell Version do you use?

Comment: Looks like 2, which is pretty out of date